# aws ec2 - running python uwsgi with bash command keeps returning --no python application found

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, flask

I'm trying to run my flask app following a tutorial written in this link - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04#configure-uwsgi

using amazon server's ec2 to run this...

Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.1 (HVM), free tiers on all options.

my file structure is as follows:

```
/home/ec2-user/login_test/login_test/app.py
                                    /wsgi.py
                         /venv/
```

so I gave a `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:8000 --protocol=http -w wsgi` command, as stated in the tutorial, "Testing uWSGI Serving" part, this returns:

`--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
[pid: 24218|app: -1|req: -1/1] 127.0.0.1 () {24 vars in 257 bytes} [Wed Apr 11 07:01:38 2018] GET / => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)`
 with browser returning `Internal Server Error`

so... what should I try and check?? the app works all fine if I activate this with without uwsgi (just `python app.py` command) and via cmd on my home computer(windows 10)

EDIT: my wsgi.py contents:

```
from app import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Comment: I tried seeing question similar but they were about setting ini files, etc.... not really with a bash command so.... :/

Comment: i think in your wsgi module you also need to import the app (app=Flask() from your app.py)
and do: -w wsgi:app

Comment: oh yes I forgot to mention.... just added my wsgi.py file contents.

Comment: if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run() wsgi will not execute this.

try -w wsgi:application

Comment: so `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:application`? um.... still the same :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a minimal working example:

wsgi.py:

```
from flask_app import app
```

flask_app.py:

from flask import Flask

```
app = Flask('my test app')

@app.route("/ping")
def ping():

    return 'pong'
```

command: `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi:app`

or without the `wsgi.py` file:
`uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w flask_app:app`

things to watch out for:

- wsgi: (the -w parameter) means you have a file called: `wsgi.py`
- app (the -w parameter) is the initiated flask object (Flask()) imported

Comment: oh so.... I shouldnt put in `app.run()` in the content at all? and `wsgi` is the `wsgi.py` itself and the `app` behind is the flask object from `from flask_app import app` right? ok.... I'll try and apply it on mine...

Comment: aaaand it worked. thank you. uuugh first time into servers and this is such a headache...

Comment: it gets easier.... :)  good luck, reading the documentation is the key! copy-paste usually will give you more effort then just reading and doing it yourself